# Google indexed page a day before also reflecting in search but today everything vanish

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt

We had *robots.txt* which disallow all robots as we were in development.

We are live now. We change *robots.txt* as per our requirement a day before.

Submit indexes using Google Webmaster Tools index status.

After this we can see proper result in search as well as Google images search was working as expected.

Suddenly today all these things vanish from Google Search. Now again I can see old result i.e. under construction message.

I checked *robots.txt* in Google Webmaster Tools, it's ok - no crawling errors.

Kindly let me know what exactly happened? How I can inform this issue to Google?

Comment: How long has it been since you went live and removed the robots.txt? What does your robots.txt file look like.

Comment: We went live 7 days back.
I updated robots.txt 5 days back and result were start displaying after 12 hours. 

So I can see appropriate content as well as images in Google search for two days, but today morning when I checked Google showing old under construction page.

I can see all activity in web master tool of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google changes his SERP and images results dynamically. Do not disturb about this. It will take approximately a month for all your images come to index stably.

If you want, you may report about it to Google, using ability from Google Webmasters Tools (at page of your sites' list in the top right corner there is the button Help. Press it and look for "Send feedback" link).

Also you can make sitemap for images and add it to your Google Webmasters Tools site profile.